# Any work around to query filter every ID in a list using in_() including duplicates?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to do something like this with SQLAlchemy:

```
Cards.query.filter(Cards.id.in_(inventory_cards)).paginate(page=page, per_page=50)
```

But the in_() operator only checks if the id is in the list and ignore duplicates. I have seen similar questions but they are not very clear or they are from 2014.

I solution I tried is loop it using a list comprehension, but as the result is a list I cannot apply the pagination afterwards. (Apart of being much slower because is making a query for every id, and sometimes there are thousands of cards in the inventory)

If anyone know a good solution for this I would appreciate it A LOT.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you need is a `JOIN`, not a `WHERE...IN` clause.

Create a temporary table with your inventory cards and join on it. Each repetition of the `id` in the temporary table will cause all matching lines to be pulled from the Cards table.

I am writing the SQL, because I do not know the correct SQLAlchemy syntax.

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE inventory_cards (
  id int
);
INSERT INTO inventory_cards VALUES ((1), (2), (3), (1), (2));
SELECT * FROM Cards JOIN inventory_cards USING (id);
```

It seems that there is a `values()` function that can create a table literal, so my guess is that it would be similar to:

```py
Cards.query.join(
  values(column("id", Integer)).data(inventory_cards)
).paginate(page=page, per_page=50)
```

Comment: I ended up solving it in a different way changing the front end, but this answer makes sense, thanks a lot, I would upvote but I don't have the reputation.